# Why the code written in asyn ngOnInit() takes effect only after refreshing the component but not right after the login?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom, typescript2.0

New to angular, doing multiple things. Today I had been assigned a task to read a webApi that returns a single value i.e. an active property. After reading, inject the add a class to `classList` of the `body` element i.e. '`activeClass`'.

The WebApi returns a `promise` from the `myservices.service.ts` and I am calling it from the `async ngOnInit` method of the `app.component.ts` and `awaiting` the result. After that I am adding the `activeClass` to the `classList` of `body`.

Now, the problem is when I login into the system then the '`activeClass`' is not getting added to the body but but when I refresh then it takes effect.

Why? This is driving me crazy. Spend around 14 hours at office and also couldn't post the issue from there since posting is not allowed there.

Roughly the code is like.

in **app.component.ts**

```
async ngOnInit () {
  const activeClass= await this.service.getData();
  document.body.classList.add(activeClass.Name.toLowerCase());
}
```

now when I login this doesn't get added to the body but the moment I refresh it starts working i.e. `body` has the `activeClass` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding it to the `app.component.ts` it means that is being called when the app initializes.

When you are not logged in, probably it calls the API, API returns null and you don't add it, but `app.component.ts` onInit or afterViewInit are not called again after login.

You have a couple of options here, but the best one would be to add this to your container to the logged in content, so it'll get initialized only after login or when you go to app and is already logged in.
Or you can extract this code, put on a shared place and call it on the `app.component.ts` and ALSO call it after you are logged in.

I'd go with the first approach if you have good architecture with the container for logged in content.

Answer (score 2):

The ngOnInit() is calling the document API which would probably return null since the view is not initialized. The solution will be to include [ngAfterViewInit()](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) to fix the issue you are facing currently.

```
export class someClass implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    const activeClass= await this.service.getData();
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.add(activeClass.Name.toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

This can also be done via another method.

```
import { Renderer2 } from ‘@angular/core’;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

async ngAfterViewInit() {
    const activeClass= await this.service.getData();
    this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, activeClass.Name.toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: hi tried now, but same issue. no effect :(

Comment: Was there any console errors in the browser?

Comment: I have modified my answer, can you try with this?